# How to swipe on recyclerview in android without dismissing

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have a project in which I need to swipe on a row in both ways in order to initiate an action.
Swiping left should remove the item in question from a specific list (without deleting it from the original one, thus leaving it be in the recyclerview dataset), and swiping right should add the item in question to another list (again not the original one).
I implemented an ItemTouchHelperAdapter and an ItemTouchHelperCallback, and I can detect the swipes right/left, however the view gets translated off the screen and I'm left with a blank rectangle. Any ideas?

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

/**
 * Called when an item has been dismissed by a swipe.<br/>
 * <br/>
 * Implementations should call {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int)} after
 * adjusting the underlying data to reflect this removal.
 *
 * @param position The position of the item dismissed.
 * @see RecyclerView#getAdapterPositionFor(RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
 * @see RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()
 */
void onItemLeftSwipe(int position);

void onItemRightSwipe(int position);
}
```

**ItemTouchHelperCallback**

```
public class ItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;

public ItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    // int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.START)
        mAdapter.onItemLeftSwipe(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.END)
        mAdapter.onItemRightSwipe(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    else
        System.out.println("direction: " + direction);
}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return true;
 }

}
```

and this is in my adapter class:

```
    @Override
public void onItemLeftSwipe(int position) {

    System.out.println("swiped left on " + mDataset.get(position).getName());

}

@Override
public void onItemRightSwipe(int position) {

    System.out.println("swiped right on " + mDataset.get(position).getName());

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        setUpRecyclerView();

    }
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter());
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        setUpItemTouchHelper();
        setUpAnimationDecoratorHelper();
    }
    private void setUpItemTouchHelper() {

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            Drawable background;
            Drawable xMark;
            int xMarkMargin;
            boolean initiated;
            private void init() {
                background = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
                xMark = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_clear_24dp);
                xMark.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                xMarkMargin = (int) MainActivity.this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ic_clear_margin);
                initiated = true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
            {
                int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                TestAdapter testAdapter = (TestAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter();
                if (testAdapter.isUndoOn() && testAdapter.isPendingRemoval(position))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                int swipedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                TestAdapter adapter = (TestAdapter)mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
                boolean undoOn = adapter.isUndoOn();
                if (undoOn) {
                    adapter.pendingRemoval(swipedPosition);
                } else {
                    adapter.remove(swipedPosition);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == -1) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!initiated) {
                    init();
                }
                background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
                background.draw(c);

                int itemHeight = itemView.getBottom() - itemView.getTop();
                int intrinsicWidth = xMark.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int intrinsicHeight = xMark.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int xMarkLeft = itemView.getRight() - xMarkMargin - intrinsicWidth;
                int xMarkRight = itemView.getRight() - xMarkMargin;
                int xMarkTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight)/2;
                int xMarkBottom = xMarkTop + intrinsicHeight;
                xMark.setBounds(xMarkLeft, xMarkTop, xMarkRight, xMarkBottom);
                xMark.draw(c);
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }

        };
        ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    }
    private void setUpAnimationDecoratorHelper() {
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
            Drawable background;
            boolean initiated;
            private void init() {
                background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
                initiated = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

                if (!initiated) {
                    init();
                }
                if (parent.getItemAnimator().isRunning())
                {
                    View lastViewComingDown = null;
                    View firstViewComingUp = null;
                    int left = parent.getHeight();
                    int right = parent.getWidth();
                    int top = 0;
                    int bottom = 0;
                    int childCount = parent.getLayoutManager().getChildCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                        View child = parent.getLayoutManager().getChildAt(i);
                        if (child.getTranslationY() < 0) {
                            // view is coming down
                            lastViewComingDown = child;
                        } else if (child.getTranslationY() > 0) {
                            // view is coming up
                            if (firstViewComingUp == null) {
                                firstViewComingUp = child;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (lastViewComingDown != null && firstViewComingUp != null) {
                        // views are coming down AND going up to fill the void
                        top = lastViewComingDown.getBottom() + (int) lastViewComingDown.getTranslationY();
                        bottom = firstViewComingUp.getTop() + (int) firstViewComingUp.getTranslationY();
                    } else if (lastViewComingDown != null) {
                        // views are going down to fill the void
                        top = lastViewComingDown.getBottom() + (int) lastViewComingDown.getTranslationY();
                        bottom = lastViewComingDown.getBottom();
                    } else if (firstViewComingUp != null) {
                        // views are coming up to fill the void
                        top = firstViewComingUp.getTop();
                        bottom = firstViewComingUp.getTop() + (int) firstViewComingUp.getTranslationY();
                    }

                    background.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
                    background.draw(c);

                }
                super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
            }

        });
    }

    class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

        private static final int PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT = 3000; // 3sec

        List<String> items;
        List<String> itemsPendingRemoval;
        int lastInsertedIndex; // so we can add some more items for testing purposes
        boolean undoOn; // is undo on, you can turn it on from the toolbar menu

        private Handler handler = new Handler(); // hanlder for running delayed runnables
        HashMap<String, Runnable> pendingRunnables = new HashMap<>(); // map of items to pending runnables, so we can cancel a removal if need be

        public TestAdapter() {
            items = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsPendingRemoval = new ArrayList<>();
            // let's generate some items
            lastInsertedIndex = 15;
            // this should give us a couple of screens worth
            for (int i=1; i<= lastInsertedIndex; i++) {
                items.add("Item " + i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new TestViewHolder(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            TestViewHolder viewHolder = (TestViewHolder)holder;
            final String item = items.get(position);

            if (itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item)) {
                // we need to show the "undo" state of the row
                //viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                viewHolder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //viewHolder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.undoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // user wants to undo the removal, let's cancel the pending task
                        Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = pendingRunnables.get(item);
                        pendingRunnables.remove(item);
                        if (pendingRemovalRunnable != null) handler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                        itemsPendingRemoval.remove(item);
                        // this will rebind the row in "normal" state
                        notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(item));
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // we need to show the "normal" state
                viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                viewHolder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(item);
                viewHolder.undoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.undoButton.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public void addItems(int howMany){
            if (howMany > 0) {
                for (int i = lastInsertedIndex + 1; i <= lastInsertedIndex + howMany; i++) {
                    items.add("Item " + i);
                    notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
                }
                lastInsertedIndex = lastInsertedIndex + howMany;
            }
        }

        public void setUndoOn(boolean undoOn) {
            this.undoOn = undoOn;
        }

        public boolean isUndoOn() {
            return undoOn;
        }

        public void pendingRemoval(int position) {
            final String item = items.get(position);
            if (!itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item)) {
                itemsPendingRemoval.add(item);
                // this will redraw row in "undo" state
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                // let's create, store and post a runnable to remove the item
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        remove(items.indexOf(item));
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(pendingRemovalRunnable, PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT);
                pendingRunnables.put(item, pendingRemovalRunnable);
            }
        }
        public void remove(int position) {
            String item = items.get(position);
            if (itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item)) {
                itemsPendingRemoval.remove(item);
            }
            if (items.contains(item)) {
                items.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }

        public boolean isPendingRemoval(int position) {
            String item = items.get(position);
            return itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item);
        }
    }
    static class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView titleTextView;
        Button undoButton;
        public TestViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)
        {
            super(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_view, parent, false));
            titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view);
            undoButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.undo_button);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to refer to the code base this code is from: https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/nemanjakovacevic/recyclerviewswipetodelete/MainActivity.java or vise versa

Comment: what are you doing here?

Comment: Could you explain the part that keeps the itemview from going off the screen? Did you manage to understand? @johnktejik

Answer (score 2):

Use this class to implement swipe listener for each item in adapter class.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

In Adapter Class:

```
itemView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
            }

            public void onSwipeRight() {

            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {

            }

            public void onSwipeBottom() {
            }

        });
```

Comment: I have to swipe many time to get one swipe working. Also `onClickListener` doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution and the most efficient one, but I just removed the item and added it again:

```
    @Override
public void onItemLeftSwipe(int position) {

    // modify your item as you wish

    mDataset.add(position, mDataset.get(position));
    notifyItemInserted(position);

    mDataset.remove(position + 1);
    notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);
}

@Override
public void onItemRightSwipe(int position) {

    // modify your item as you wish

    mDataset.add(position, mDataset.get(position));
    notifyItemInserted(position);

    mDataset.remove(position + 1);
    notifyItemRemoved(position + 1);
}
```