# How to set RecyclerView OnClickListener an OnLongClickListener in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to start a new Fragment that shows the details of the item that was clicked on in the RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is on a Fragments. I've tried this in Activities and it worked perfectly but I'm trying to convert it to use on Fragments. And Also, how to detect other gestures in the RecyclerView (swipe, etc...)

My Adapter :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private final ArrayList<Tip> dataSet;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewType;
    //TextView textViewDetail;
    ImageView imageViewImage;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        this.textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.textViewType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        //this.textViewDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        this.imageViewImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Tip> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate( R.layout.item, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(HomeFragment.myOnClickListener);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int listPosition) {

    TextView textViewTitle = holder.textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewType = holder.textViewType;
    //TextView textViewDetail = holder.textViewDetail;
    ImageView imageViewImage = holder.imageViewImage;

    textViewTitle.setText( dataSet.get(listPosition).getTitle() );
    textViewType.setText( dataSet.get(listPosition).getType() );
    //textViewDetail.setText( dataSet.get(listPosition).getDetail() );
    imageViewImage.setImageResource( dataSet.get(listPosition).getImage() );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
```

}

My Fragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static RecyclerView.Adapter myAdapter;
private static RecyclerView.LayoutManager myLayoutManager;
private static RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
public static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;

private static ArrayList<Tip> myData;




public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get the integer from the integers.xml resource file
    Resources res = getResources();
    int gridColumnCount = res.getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



    // Add the following lines to create RecyclerView
    myRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( view.getContext() );
    myLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( view.getContext(),gridColumnCount );

    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager( myLayoutManager );
    myRecyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );

    myData = new ArrayList<Tip>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MyData.tipTitleArray.length; i++) {
        myData.add(new Tip( MyData.tipTitleArray[i], MyData.tipTypeArray[i], MyData.tipDetailArray[i], MyData.id_[i], MyData.tipImageArray[i] ));

    }

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myData);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
//On retourne la View
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    fr.cnam.smb116.mimi_tips_navdraw.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding binding = null;
}
```

}

Comment: To add swipes in RecyclerView, check out here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388676/how-to-swipe-on-recyclerview-in-android-without-dismissing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static listener and recyclerview instance.
Better to add callBack function to handle this.
e.g

```
interface RecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> {
  void onClick(int position, T data);
}
```

init property in your adapter

```
RecyclerViewItemClickListener<Tip> listener
```

constructor of your Adapter

```
MyAdapter(RecyclerViewItemClickListener<Tip> listener) {
   this. listener = listener
}
```

in

```
onBindViewHolder() {
   holder.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      listener.onClick(position, dataSet.get(listPosition));
   })
}
```

In Your Fragment
Implement this interface

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewItemClickListener<Tip> {
 
}
```

your adapter instance

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myData,this);
```

implement onClick Method in your fragment

```
void onClick(int position, Tip tip){
// your listener
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot Muhammad, it work like a charm :-)